# javascript returns null on first click only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a modal that displays images for the client to viewer in larger form. and slides left and then slides the new image in from the left on click. When I click on the thumbnail on the page it is displays in the modal perfectly. But when I click on the first modal displaying image it returns null and the left settings is off. but when I click on the new image all is well and works perfectly from there on out. Why does it return null and how do I stop it.

***CODE***

```
  $( '#modal img').live('click',function(e){
    var index = $(this).attr('img_index');
    var img_og = $( '#viewer ul li img[img_index="' + index + '"] ');
    var imgOgWidth= img_og.width();
    index++;
    if(index > $( '#viewer ul li img').length ) {index = 0;}
    var left = ($( window ).width() - imgOgWidth  )/ 2;
    var src = img_og.attr('src');
    console.log($( window ).width() + " - " + img_og.width() + " = " + left);
    $(this).animate({"left":'-2000px'},300,function(){
        $(this).attr({'src':src,'img_index':index}).css({'width':imgOgWidth,"left":'2000px'}).animate({'left':left},300);
    });
});
```

***CONSOLE.LOG***

```
1288 - null = 644
1288 - 470 = 409
1288 - 900 = 194
1288 - 900 = 194
1288 - 900 = 194
```

***HTML***

```
<div id="modal" class="none">
<img src="" img_index="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you define img_og width initially onload?

Comment: html added, and no I'm not defining img_og onLoad

Comment: So at what point do you populate img_index?

Comment: Deep in the php file. There is a ul with each image I use for referencing.

Comment: @Cjueden See if you can reproduce the bug in a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and then post the link in your question.

Comment: I can't do that as the images are only on my local :\

Comment: @Cjueden This problem won't be with your images, just use images you can find online. Google something like "[funny pictures of cats](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=pictures%20of%20cats&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=2144&bih=1195&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=qD9tULetAY3C0AWStIHgAg#um=1&hl=en&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=funny+pictures+of+cats&oq=funny+pictures+of+cats&gs_l=img.3..0l9j0i5.50325.51305.0.51569.6.6.0.0.0.1.220.714.3j2j1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.vxdISn3Z0K4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=c2351b28d8622e6b&biw=2144&bih=1195)" and link to those as `src`

Comment: no I can't I'm sry I've been working on this for the last 30 mins. thank you for you willingness to help!!!

Comment: I've solved the problem, I was trying to access the "new" picture before incrementing the index. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem, I was trying to access the "new" picture before incrementing the index. Thank you for your help.